# Tried installing summarize gem in Windows 7 and got an error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I tried installing the summarize gem on my windows PC and it gave an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing summarize:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating summarize-i386-mingw32.def
compiling article.c
In file included from article.c:25:0:
libots.h:24:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [article.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Is it possible to overcome this easily? What is the solution?

Comment: did you install DevKit?

Comment: @uDaY yeah, i have railsinstaller installed on my computer and it includes devkit as well.